# How can I analysis many real time data effectively?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently developing a tool for user web actions analysis.
The real-time user action data comes to about 3000 objects per second. 
I'm capturing the real-time data using python.

I want to analyse many user action data:

1. How many left/right mouse buttons were clicked in total?
2. How many left/right mouse buttons were clicked with action A (B, C, D, E, ...)?
3. How many left/right mouse buttons were clicked with action A (B, C, D, E, ...) in an hour?
4. How many same action is done by same time?

I want to know how to efficiently analyse these many real-time data.

Also, I'm saving these data in a database, but I want to know that analytics as real-time.
Also, I'm utilising quite a few `If-Else` stanzas, which seems less than optimal code. 
Basically, I'm looking for the best approach to analysis many data in real-time.

My main question is..

1. How to process coming so many datas as real-time? Queue? or what else?
2. How to analysis many type of analytics? I just doing it with using many `If-Else` phrases.
3. Can I use numpy, pandas or else for analysis these data?

Below code is some of my code.

Coming data object looks like:

```
{
    "usercode": row['usercode'],
    "actiontime": row['actiontime'],
    "actioncode": row['actioncode'],
    "mousebutton": row['mousebutton']
}
```

Data processing logic:

```
config_action_threshold = 10
config_moment_threshold = 4

memory_collector = dict() 
memory_action = dict()
memory_action_hourly = dict()
memory_moment = dict() 

def addData(item):
    if item['usercode'] not in memory_collector:
        memory_collector[item['usercode']] = {"leftclick":0,"rightclick":0,"actions":0}
        memory_action[item['usercode']] = dict()
        memory_action_hourly[item['usercode']] = {"0006":{},"0612":{},"1218":{},"1824":{}}
        memory_moment[item['usercode']] = {"actiontime":0,"count":0}

    collector = memory_collector[item['usercode']]
    action = memory_action[item['usercode']]
    action_hourly = memory_action_hourly[item['usercode']]
    moment = memory_moment[item['usercode']]

    #normalizing
    if item['actioncode'] not in action:
        action[item['actioncode']] = {"actionL":0,"actionR":0,"actionA":0,"actionB":0}
    actioncode = action[item['actioncode']]

    if item['mousebutton'] == 'L':
        actioncode['L'] += 1
    else:
        actioncode['R'] += 1

    # I have to use if condition because count up when the action occurs over `config_action_threshold`
    if actioncode['L'] >= config_action_threshold:
        if collector['actionL'] == 0:
            collector['actionL'] += config_action_threshold
        else:
            collector['actionL'] += 1

    if actioncode['R'] >= config_action_threshold:
        if collector['actionR'] == 0:
            collector['actionR'] += config_action_threshold
        else:
            collector['actionR'] += 1

    if actioncode['actionA'] >= config_action_threshold:
        if collector['actionA'] == 0:
            collector['actionA'] += config_action_threshold
        else:
            collector['actionA'] += 1

    if actioncode['actionB'] >= config_action_threshold:
        if collector['actionB'] == 0:
            collector['actionB'] += config_action_threshold
        else:
            collector['actionB'] += 1

    if (moment['actiontime'] == item['actiontime']):
        moment['count'] += 1
        if moment['count'] == config_moment_threshold:
            collector['moment'] += config_moment_threshold
        elif moment['count'] > config_moment_threshold:
            collector['moment'] += 1
    else:
        moment['actiontime'] = item['actiontime']
        moment['count'] = 0
```

Comment: Have you considered concurrency? If you have access to a multi-core machine, or to a cluster of machines, you may break your problem to concurrent threads/processes.

Comment: I would look into building a web frontend for a [time series database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database) with [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) or something else that can handle thousands of concurrent connections.

Comment: +1 on @Blender's idea [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits) can handle many thousands of concurrent connections too!